# SQLite with C# - UPDATE Command with Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, parameters

I am creating a program where you can store and change the balances of different accounts in visual C#. At the moment I am making the part where you can add to the balance of an account stored in a database to a table like this:

[image: Customers Database]

After adding on an amount of money, thus changing the currency, I want to be able to change the currency value in the database.

For example, if the current currency of an account (record) is £2. After adding on £3 I want to change the database so in the currency field for that record it now says £5.

I have written this code which is similar to how I inserted information into the database earlier in the code which worked successfully but I can't figure out how to use the syntax for the update command whilst using parameters in this context (**doesn't work**):

```
string sql = "update customers set balance values ('" + balance + "') where first_name values ('" + forename + "')";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

(This is the code I used earlier to insert information into the table that **works**):

```
string sql = "insert into leaders (ID, username, password, first_name, last_name) values (null,'" + username + "', '" + password + "', '" + first_name + "', '" + last_name + "')";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using the correct syntax for `update`:

```
string sql = "update customers set balance = '" + balance + "' where first_name = '" + forename + "'";
```

Note that this is **not** a parameterized query, and might be vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks (or just break if one of the values contains a `'`). It's recommended to use a prepared statement with parameters:

```
string sql = "update customers set balance = @balance where first_name = @forename";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", balance);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@forename", forename);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```